# How to take screenshot of Form from within app?

Tags: forms, vb6, screenshot, clipboard

What code would effectively take a screenshot of a `Form` and put a copy of this image on to the clipboard?

So I would like something like: `Form.CopyScreenshotToClipboard`

Comment: [My answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10123008/588306) gives code to get a screenshot of a window.

Comment: @Deann +1 to Deanna. Use frm.hWnd to determine the hWnd of a form, which is all you need to use Deanna's answer

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a hidden PictureBox at design time
2. Use [Deanna's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10123008/588306) to get the form drawn into a PictureBox. Use form.hWnd to get the hWnd
3. Then copy the picturebox contents onto the clipboard [like this](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Tips/Copy_the_entire_contents_of_a_PictureBox_to_the_Clipboard/article.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, what about simulating ALT+PRNSCN when your form is the focused form?

This will make a screenshot of the form and put it in the clipboard.