# Screen Capture Specific Window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gdi

Is it possible to screen capture a specific window (also possibly of  another process)?

Currently I am capturing the entire desktop of a specific monitor, however what I truly want is to capture the content of a specific window (regardless of its position).

Comment: It is straightforward: you do a `BitBlt` from desktop DC into your bitmap. For specific window you copy not the entire desktop, but just the rectangle of your interest (which is `GetWindowRect` of your specific window). Yes it can be a window of another process.

Comment: Roman R. How do I find the rectangle of interest? Is there any way to iterate over all windows and find their rectangles?

Comment: If you have specific window, then you have its `HWND` handle. `GetWindowRect` gives you its screen coordinates.

Comment: I don't have any handle, only the name of the window.

Comment: `FindWindow` gets you the `HWND` then. Or, you need to `EnumWindows` to find the one you need, and its handle.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes it is. All what you need is get handle to window which you want to capture and use WinAPI function PrintWindow for example:

```
// Get the window handle of calculator application.
HWND hWnd = ::FindWindow( 0, _T( "Calculator" ));

// Take screenshot.
PrintWindow( hWnd, getDC(hWnd), 0 );
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162869%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you have PrintWindow documentation.

Comment: What if this window is not focused or is hidden, behind other windows, can this still work?

Comment: How to proceed and save the screenshot (or get the data) after PrintWindow?

Comment: From the [PrintWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162869.aspx) documentation: *"The application that owns the window referenced by hWnd [...] receives a WM_PRINT message or [...] a WM_PRINTCLIENT message."* - In other words: The source window must implement a `WM_PRINT`/`WM_PRINTCLIENT` message handler. If it doesn't, `PrintWindow` won't work. This is not a general solution.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, Just as easy as capturing the full screen. You just use `GetWindowDC()` on the required window rather than `GetDesktopWindow()`, then `BitBlt()` from that to your target DC. You can also get the correct size by using `GetWindowRect()`.

Note that this method also allows you to capture from hidden/covered windows where a full screenshot with a bounding rectangle doesn't.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10123008/588306) for some more details.

Comment: please answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66007306/how-to-capture-specific-window-using-windows-gdi

Answer (score 3):

There is a new API in Windows 10 in `winrt/Windows.Graphics.Capture.h`
There is a very complex example here by Microsoft:
https://github.com/microsoft/Windows.UI.Composition-Win32-Samples/tree/master/cpp/ScreenCaptureforHWND

I wanted to create some dirty example (very dirty) and in my example, you have a simple function that gets `HWND` of a window and captures it, and saves it as `ScreenShot.bmp`

Note that the error handling in this function is bad.
You are welcome to improve this answer!

NOTES:

- It should work perfectly for any Window. Even if the window does not have `WDA_NONE` display affinity (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowdisplayaffinity)
- It should work also when the window is offscreen or covered by another window. It will get the full window frame even if part of it is not visible on the screen
- There is a limitation that you will see a yellow border around the window for a very short time during the capture process

Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <dxgi.h>
#include <inspectable.h>
#include <dxgi1_2.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.System.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Graphics.Capture.h>
#include <windows.graphics.capture.interop.h>
#include <windows.graphics.directx.direct3d11.interop.h>
#include <roerrorapi.h>
#include <shlobj_core.h>
#include <dwmapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"Dwmapi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"windowsapp.lib")


void CaptureWindow(HWND hwndTarget)
{
    // Init COM
    winrt::init_apartment(winrt::apartment_type::multi_threaded);
    
    // Create Direct 3D Device
    winrt::com_ptr<ID3D11Device> d3dDevice;

    winrt::check_hresult(D3D11CreateDevice(nullptr, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, nullptr, D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT,
                                           nullptr, 0,D3D11_SDK_VERSION, d3dDevice.put(), nullptr, nullptr));


    winrt::Windows::Graphics::DirectX::Direct3D11::IDirect3DDevice device;
    const auto dxgiDevice = d3dDevice.as<IDXGIDevice>();
    {
        winrt::com_ptr<::IInspectable> inspectable;
        winrt::check_hresult(CreateDirect3D11DeviceFromDXGIDevice(dxgiDevice.get(), inspectable.put()));
        device = inspectable.as<winrt::Windows::Graphics::DirectX::Direct3D11::IDirect3DDevice>();
    }


    auto idxgiDevice2 = dxgiDevice.as<IDXGIDevice2>();
    winrt::com_ptr<IDXGIAdapter> adapter;
    winrt::check_hresult(idxgiDevice2->GetParent(winrt::guid_of<IDXGIAdapter>(), adapter.put_void()));
    winrt::com_ptr<IDXGIFactory2> factory;
    winrt::check_hresult(adapter->GetParent(winrt::guid_of<IDXGIFactory2>(), factory.put_void()));

    ID3D11DeviceContext* d3dContext = nullptr;
    d3dDevice->GetImmediateContext(&d3dContext);

    RECT rect{};
    DwmGetWindowAttribute(hwndTarget, DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS, &rect, sizeof(RECT));
    const auto size = winrt::Windows::Graphics::SizeInt32{rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top};

    winrt::Windows::Graphics::Capture::Direct3D11CaptureFramePool m_framePool =
        winrt::Windows::Graphics::Capture::Direct3D11CaptureFramePool::Create(
            device,
            winrt::Windows::Graphics::DirectX::DirectXPixelFormat::B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized,
            2,
            size);

    const auto activationFactory = winrt::get_activation_factory<
        winrt::Windows::Graphics::Capture::GraphicsCaptureItem>();
    auto interopFactory = activationFactory.as<IGraphicsCaptureItemInterop>();
    winrt::Windows::Graphics::Capture::GraphicsCaptureItem captureItem = {nullptr};
    interopFactory->CreateForWindow(hwndTarget, winrt::guid_of<ABI::Windows::Graphics::Capture::IGraphicsCaptureItem>(),
                                    reinterpret_cast<void**>(winrt::put_abi(captureItem)));

    auto isFrameArrived = false;
    winrt::com_ptr<ID3D11Texture2D> texture;
    const auto session = m_framePool.CreateCaptureSession(captureItem);
    m_framePool.FrameArrived([&](auto& framePool, auto&)
    {
        if (isFrameArrived) return;
        auto frame = framePool.TryGetNextFrame();

        struct __declspec(uuid("A9B3D012-3DF2-4EE3-B8D1-8695F457D3C1"))
            IDirect3DDxgiInterfaceAccess : ::IUnknown
        {
            virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetInterface(GUID const& id, void** object) = 0;
        };

        auto access = frame.Surface().as<IDirect3DDxgiInterfaceAccess>();
        access->GetInterface(winrt::guid_of<ID3D11Texture2D>(), texture.put_void());
        isFrameArrived = true;
        return;
    });


    session.IsCursorCaptureEnabled(false);
    session.StartCapture();


    // Message pump
    MSG msg;
    clock_t timer = clock();
    while (!isFrameArrived)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) > 0)
            DispatchMessage(&msg);

        if (clock() - timer > 20000)
        {
            // TODO: try to make here a better error handling
            return;
        }
    }

    session.Close();

    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC capturedTextureDesc;
    texture->GetDesc(&capturedTextureDesc);

    capturedTextureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
    capturedTextureDesc.BindFlags = 0;
    capturedTextureDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
    capturedTextureDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

    winrt::com_ptr<ID3D11Texture2D> userTexture = nullptr;
    winrt::check_hresult(d3dDevice->CreateTexture2D(&capturedTextureDesc, NULL, userTexture.put()));

    d3dContext->CopyResource(userTexture.get(), texture.get());


    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE resource;
    winrt::check_hresult(d3dContext->Map(userTexture.get(), NULL, D3D11_MAP_READ, 0, &resource));

    BITMAPINFO lBmpInfo;

    // BMP 32 bpp
    ZeroMemory(&lBmpInfo, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));
    lBmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    lBmpInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    lBmpInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    lBmpInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = capturedTextureDesc.Width;
    lBmpInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = capturedTextureDesc.Height;
    lBmpInfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    lBmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = capturedTextureDesc.Width * capturedTextureDesc.Height * 4;
    
    std::unique_ptr<BYTE> pBuf(new BYTE[lBmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage]);
    UINT lBmpRowPitch = capturedTextureDesc.Width * 4;
    auto sptr = static_cast<BYTE*>(resource.pData);
    auto dptr = pBuf.get() + lBmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage - lBmpRowPitch;

    UINT lRowPitch = std::min<UINT>(lBmpRowPitch, resource.RowPitch);

    for (size_t h = 0; h < capturedTextureDesc.Height; ++h)
    {
        memcpy_s(dptr, lBmpRowPitch, sptr, lRowPitch);
        sptr += resource.RowPitch;
        dptr -= lBmpRowPitch;
    }

    // Save bitmap buffer into the file ScreenShot.bmp
    WCHAR lMyDocPath[MAX_PATH];

    winrt::check_hresult(SHGetFolderPath(nullptr, CSIDL_PERSONAL, nullptr, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, lMyDocPath));

    std::wstring lFilePath = L"ScreenShot.bmp";

    FILE* lfile = nullptr;

    if (auto lerr = _wfopen_s(&lfile, lFilePath.c_str(), L"wb"); lerr != 0)
        return;

    if (lfile != nullptr)
    {
        BITMAPFILEHEADER bmpFileHeader;

        bmpFileHeader.bfReserved1 = 0;
        bmpFileHeader.bfReserved2 = 0;
        bmpFileHeader.bfSize = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + lBmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage;
        bmpFileHeader.bfType = 'MB';
        bmpFileHeader.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

        fwrite(&bmpFileHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, lfile);
        fwrite(&lBmpInfo.bmiHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, lfile);
        fwrite(pBuf.get(), lBmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage, 1, lfile);

        fclose(lfile);
    }

    return;
}
```

How to use:

```cpp
auto targetHwnd = FindWindow(L"Notepad",NULL); // Or user any other HWND
CaptureWindow(targetHwnd); // If it worked, it will create ScreenShot.bmp file
```

Comment: Thanks for this code example, it works. However, more issues are that the performance of this screen dumping code is very bad (400 - 800 ms) and that the code is pretty complex to understand. Also it seems to increase compilation time by a lot which is unfortunate. Also, is there a clever way to get a PNG instead of a BMP without writing to the disk and loading it back using e.g. `GDIPlus`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68749555

Comment: jfyi, the yellow border limitation can be removed by setting `IsBorderRequired(false)` on session object.

Answer (score 0):

When I want to draw the screen of a game on a notepad, only the **black** screen will be displayed by using the following method.

```golang
hdcGame := GetDC(hwndGame)
BitBlt(hdcNotpad, 0, 0, rectGame.Width(), rectGame.Height(),
       hdcGame, 0, 0,
       SRCCOPY
)
```

So I try @Roman R.'s suggestion to capture the desktop DC<sup>`GetDC(GetDesktopWindow())`</sup> and then calculate the target position<sup>[GetWindowRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowrect)</sup> of our screen and draw only that position.<sup>[BitBlt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-bitblt) or [StretchBlt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-stretchblt)</sup>

### Example

The following code is implemented by go

```golang
// draw the calculator's screen on the notepad
func Example_captureWindow() {
    user32dll := w32.NewUser32DLL()
    gdi32dll := w32.NewGdi32DLL()

    hwndScreen := user32dll.GetDesktopWindow()
    hdcScreen := user32dll.GetDC(hwndScreen)
    defer user32dll.ReleaseDC(hwndScreen, hdcScreen) // release when exit function

    hwndCalculator := user32dll.FindWindow("ApplicationFrameWindow", "小算盤")
    hwndNotepad := user32dll.FindWindow("Notepad", "")

    hdcNotepad := user32dll.GetWindowDC(hwndNotepad)
    defer user32dll.ReleaseDC(hwndNotepad, hdcNotepad)

    var rectNotepad w32.RECT
    var rectC w32.RECT
    gdi32dll.SetStretchBltMode(hdcNotepad, w32.HALFTONE)
    user32dll.GetWindowRect(hwndNotepad, &rectNotepad)
    user32dll.GetWindowRect(hwndCalculator, &rectC)
    gdi32dll.StretchBlt(
        hdcNotepad, rectNotepad.Width()/4, rectNotepad.Height()/4, rectNotepad.Width()/2, rectNotepad.Height()/2, // draw screen on the center
        hdcScreen, rectC.Left, rectC.Top, rectC.Width(), rectC.Height(), w32.SRCCOPY,
    )
}
```

#### other example:

1. Capture the [Calculator's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Calculator) screen every 0.1 seconds and then draw it on the notepad : [source link](https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/go-pkg/blob/46c0d16ea2f92919c6094b61421fb7c0d15fb324/v2/w32/user32_func_test.go#L1890-L1961)
2. Press F9 can capture the specific device screen and show it on the notepad. [source link](https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/go-pkg/blob/46c0d16ea2f92919c6094b61421fb7c0d15fb324/v2/w32/user32_func_test.go#L1805-L1888)