# Get screencapture of running applications separately and parallely

Tags: java, remote-desktop, screen-capture

I'm trying to implement an application which will work like a remote desktop application, however it should let the user spread all GUI applications and see them separately.

I'm trying to do this in Java, however I am willing to work with other languages as well if functionality is supported.

Currently I have succeeded in at least implementing the remote desktop part using [AWT Robot's screencapture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture%28java.awt.Rectangle%29). I'm sending the images at fixed intervals to the client.

To find the clues I have gone through the [sourceforge jrDesktop](http://jrdesktop.sourceforge.net/) project and found that this is also using the same [screenCapture method here](https://sourceforge.net/p/jrdesktop/code/HEAD/tree/jrdesktop/src/jrdesktop/server/robot.java).

For the second part of the problem, I need to show all the windows simultaneously. like having multiple screens attached to the machine with one application per screen.

I don't know if it's possible to get that rendering information of each application simultaneously.

Right now I'm willing to settle for creating a very large resolution virtual screen and spreading the applications on this screen on the client, something like VNC server as it's able to define the resolution of the screen. It would be great to get some pointers here, if there are any opensource projects preferably in Java but not limited to, which can help in doing this.

However I would like to solve it without the a single large screen.

Any help is appreciated.

My current POC code is here https://github.com/ConsciousObserver/Robot, it's not optimized yet.

Comment: This can be accomplished by using JNA. Just grab window handles, get dimensions/position/state (minimized, etc.), draw it, convert to Java's object (e.g. BufferedImage), etc. I don't know how it would work for windows that are overlapped on win/mac/*nix. But you'll have to write code for every platform you want to support.

Comment: Thanks @Xeon, I just looked at the C++ options on windows wit JNA, I think this can work. In this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283015/screen-capture-specific-window, Blood confirms that this method can capture hidden windows. I will have to test it.