# Real-time Screen Capturing of a Specific Application

Tags: c++, windows, screen-capture

I am working on a program to capture *real-time* `video frames` from a specific application i.e. Microsoft Word.

> Currently, I am capturing the entire desktop of the windows machine,
> and If shuffle from one application to another application, it is
> capturing everything on the screen.

[image]

*Using this article:* [The Sink writer to Encode Video](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/tutorial--using-the-sink-writer-to-encode-video?redirectedfrom=MSDN), I have managed to implement this simple program in `c++` such as;

```
// Required Components
#pragma comment(lib, "mfreadwrite")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfplat")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfuuid")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d9.lib")

#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

#include <mfapi.h>
#include <mfidl.h>
#include <Mfreadwrite.h>
#include <mferror.h>
#include <d3d9.h>


template<class T>
void SafeRelease(T **ppT) {

    if (*ppT) {
        (*ppT)->Release();
        *ppT = NULL;
    }
}

#define REVERSE_IMAGE

// Format constants
const UINT32 VIDEO_FPS = 30;
const UINT64 VIDEO_FRAME_DURATION = 10 * 1000 * 1000 / VIDEO_FPS;
const UINT32 VIDEO_BIT_RATE = 800000000;
const GUID VIDEO_ENCODING_FORMAT = MFVideoFormat_H264;
const GUID VIDEO_INPUT_FORMAT = MFVideoFormat_RGB32;
const UINT32 VIDEO_FRAME_COUNT = 10 * VIDEO_FPS;

HRESULT
InitializeDirect3D9(IDirect3DDevice9 **ppDevice, IDirect3DSurface9 **ppSurface, UINT32 &uiWidth, UINT32 &uiHeight) {

    IDirect3D9 *d3d = NULL;

    d3d = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);

    if (d3d == NULL)
        return E_POINTER;

    D3DDISPLAYMODE mode;
    HRESULT hr = d3d->GetAdapterDisplayMode(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, &mode);

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        SafeRelease(&d3d);
        return hr;
    }

    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS parameters = {0};

    parameters.Windowed = TRUE;
    parameters.BackBufferCount = 1;
    uiHeight = parameters.BackBufferHeight = mode.Height;
    uiWidth = parameters.BackBufferWidth = mode.Width;
    parameters.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    parameters.hDeviceWindow = NULL;

    hr = d3d->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, NULL, D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &parameters,
                           ppDevice);

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        SafeRelease(&d3d);
        return hr;
    }

    hr = (*ppDevice)->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(mode.Width, mode.Height, D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM,
                                                  ppSurface, nullptr);

    SafeRelease(&d3d);

    return hr;
}

HRESULT
InitializeSinkWriter(IMFSinkWriter **ppWriter, DWORD *pStreamIndex, const UINT32 uiWidth, const UINT32 uiHeight) {

    *ppWriter = NULL;
    *pStreamIndex = NULL;

    IMFSinkWriter *pSinkWriter = NULL;
    IMFMediaType *pMediaTypeOut = NULL;
    IMFMediaType *pMediaTypeIn = NULL;
    DWORD streamIndex;

    HRESULT hr = MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL(L"output.mp4", NULL, NULL, &pSinkWriter);

    // Set the output media type.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = MFCreateMediaType(&pMediaTypeOut);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = pMediaTypeOut->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = pMediaTypeOut->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, VIDEO_ENCODING_FORMAT);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = pMediaTypeOut->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE, VIDEO_BIT_RATE);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = pMediaTypeOut->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlace_Progressive);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = MFSetAttributeSize(pMediaTypeOut, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, uiWidth, uiHeight);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeOut, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, VIDEO_FPS, 1);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeOut, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = pSinkWriter->AddStream(pMediaTypeOut, &streamIndex);
    }

    // Set the input media type.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = MFCreateMediaType(&pMediaTypeIn);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = pMediaTypeIn->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = pMediaTypeIn->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, VIDEO_INPUT_FORMAT);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = pMediaTypeIn->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlace_Progressive);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = MFSetAttributeSize(pMediaTypeIn, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, uiWidth, uiHeight);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeIn, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, VIDEO_FPS, 1);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeIn, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = pSinkWriter->SetInputMediaType(streamIndex, pMediaTypeIn, NULL);
    }

    // Tell the sink writer to start accepting data.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = pSinkWriter->BeginWriting();
    }

    // Return the pointer to the caller.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {

        *ppWriter = pSinkWriter;
        (*ppWriter)->AddRef();
        *pStreamIndex = streamIndex;
    }

    SafeRelease(&pSinkWriter);
    SafeRelease(&pMediaTypeOut);
    SafeRelease(&pMediaTypeIn);
    return hr;
}

HRESULT WriteFrame(IDirect3DDevice9 *pDevice, IDirect3DSurface9 *pSurface, IMFSinkWriter *pWriter, DWORD streamIndex,
                   const LONGLONG &rtStart, const UINT32 uiWidth, const UINT32 uiHeight) {

    HRESULT hr = pDevice->GetFrontBufferData(0, pSurface);

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        return hr;
    }

    D3DLOCKED_RECT rc;
    hr = pSurface->LockRect(&rc, NULL, 0);

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        return hr;
    }

    IMFSample *pSample = NULL;
    IMFMediaBuffer *pBuffer = NULL;

    const LONG cbWidth = 4 * uiWidth;
    const DWORD cbBuffer = cbWidth * uiHeight;

    BYTE *pData = NULL;

    // Create a new memory buffer.
    hr = MFCreateMemoryBuffer(cbBuffer, &pBuffer);

    // Lock the buffer and copy the video frame to the buffer.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = pBuffer->Lock(&pData, NULL, NULL);
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {

#ifdef REVERSE_IMAGE
        for (int i = 0, j = uiHeight - 1; i < uiHeight; i++, j--)
            for (int k = 0; k < cbWidth; k++)
                pData[(i * cbWidth) + k] = ((BYTE *) rc.pBits)[(j * cbWidth) + k];
#else
        hr = MFCopyImage(pData, cbWidth, (BYTE*)rc.pBits, rc.Pitch, cbWidth, uiHeight);
#endif
    }

    if (pBuffer) {
        pBuffer->Unlock();
    }

    // Set the data length of the buffer.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = pBuffer->SetCurrentLength(cbBuffer);
    }

    // Create a media sample and add the buffer to the sample.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = MFCreateSample(&pSample);
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = pSample->AddBuffer(pBuffer);
    }

    // Set the time stamp and the duration.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = pSample->SetSampleTime(rtStart);
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = pSample->SetSampleDuration(VIDEO_FRAME_DURATION);
    }

    // Send the sample to the Sink Writer.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = pWriter->WriteSample(streamIndex, pSample);
    }

    hr = pSurface->UnlockRect();

    SafeRelease(&pSample);
    SafeRelease(&pBuffer);
    return hr;
}


void start_engine(){

    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {

        hr = MFStartup(MF_VERSION);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {

            //4k = 3840 x 2160
            UINT32 uiWidth = 3840;
            UINT32 uiHeight = 2160;

            IDirect3DDevice9 *pDevice = NULL;
            IDirect3DSurface9 *pSurface = NULL;

            hr = InitializeDirect3D9(&pDevice, &pSurface, uiWidth, uiHeight);

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {

                IMFSinkWriter *pSinkWriter = NULL;
                DWORD stream;

                hr = InitializeSinkWriter(&pSinkWriter, &stream, uiWidth, uiHeight);

                if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {

                    LONGLONG rtStart = 0;

                    for (DWORD i = 0; i < VIDEO_FRAME_COUNT; ++i) {

                        hr = WriteFrame(pDevice, pSurface, pSinkWriter, stream, rtStart, uiWidth, uiHeight);

                        if (FAILED(hr)) {
                            break;
                        }

                        rtStart += VIDEO_FRAME_DURATION;
                    }
                }

                if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                    hr = pSinkWriter->Finalize();
                }

                SafeRelease(&pSinkWriter);
            }

            SafeRelease(&pDevice);
            SafeRelease(&pSurface);
            MFShutdown();
        }

        CoUninitialize();
    }


}

int main() {

    std::cout << "Screen Capturing has started..." << std::endl;
    start_engine();
    std::cout << "Check: 'output.mp4' in the same directory." << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

This program is working fine, I have tested it on different `FPS` i.e. (`30`, `60`), `bitrate`, and by changing the `video encoder`. What I truly want is to capture the content of a **specific window** (regardless of its `Position/Size`) i.e. Microsoft Word.

I have tried the answers in the following article;

- [Screen Capture Specific Window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11283070/10413749)
- [Quite lengthy and Complex Example](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows.UI.Composition-Win32-Samples/tree/master/cpp/ScreenCaptureforHWND)

However, I am unable to capture frames from a specific Window. Video Frames are quite important for me as I want to write those frames to an `MP4` file to observe and improve the video quality by using this program.

> I am working on `WinAPI` in parallel to check if that might help me to
> get the required functionality in order to obtain video frames.

Is it possible to get video frames from the screen capturing a specific window i.e. `Microsoft Word` (Definitely When Microsft Word is opened.)?

If someone can help me to modify this current implementation that would be a great help, Indeed. I need some programmatic examples or advice. Thanks

Comment: OBS is open source and can do want you want.  Perhaps you could look at it's source code - https://obsproject.com/

Comment: I have worked with OBS and I am able to get the required screen captured using OBS `UDP sockets` and obtained in my program. I have also worked with `Nvidia CloudXR` for capturing frames. 

Actually, I am doing this from scratch. My current program is running perfectly, I just want to capture the screen of any specific Application using this program.