# How can i take a screenshot of a specific control?

Tags: vb6, richtextbox, screenshot

Im working with a vb6 application that generates barcodes. one of the functions is to save the barcode as an image. currently it takes the whole form as a screenshot [image: like this]

anyways, i would like to know how to (if possible) only take a screenshot of the rich text box from the main form (Left one) and put it on the preview (right one).

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10123008/1070452

Comment: that code will allow me to take a screenshot of just the rich textbox?

Comment: it should, though it might have to be modified to do so.  you'd use the `hWnd` of the RTB rather than form.

Comment: where would i enter the hwnd of the rtb?

Comment: its a functon `GetScreenshot(Optional ByVal hWnd As Long = 0)` so pass it the `hWnd` of the RTB to it.  It should work on anything you can get an hWnd for.

Comment: yeah i just wrote `RTBarcode.hWnd` and it is working now! thanks so much @Plutonix!

Comment: upvote the answer (link) if it helped...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Basic RBG Capture from Screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677580/visual-basic-rbg-capture-from-screen)