# Application - Screen Shot

Tags: vb6, screenshot

Currently I'm working on a few legacy applications built with VB6. What I'm trying to do is somehow be able to built a SCREEN SHOT feature into the applications so that on ERROR, the application will automatically take a screen shot of the ERROR - since i've come to find out a lot of users don't know how to do that.

The system in place is actually pretty neat, as we have a table in SQL SERVER that log in all application errors. However, some applications don't do that. I'm looking to somehow be able to incorporate the screen shot feature into the application and have it emailed to helpDesk@company.

Is something like that doable? Thoughts?

Comment: is this doable? what language if it is doable? Anyone? Anyone has ever done this?

Comment: I am sure this is doable in .net, as I currently have this exact feature working in production code written in vb.net

Comment: You can also look at this question regarding vb6 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677580/visual-basic-rbg-capture-from-screen/10123008#10123008

Comment: @Verdolino this answered my question and more. Post as answer! Thank you.